# Why is OleDbConnection access denied?

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection, sql-server-2014

Why is OleDbConnection access denied (SQL Server 2014)?

```
string connectionString =
"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=UserInfo;Data Source=C:\\...\\SqlServerDbExample.mdf.;Trusted_Connection=False";

OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

Result: SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Intentionally misspelling of the Provider name results in a different message:

'xxxSQLOLEDB.1' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: Have you tried Provider using "." ? does it connect with current server ?

Answer (score 0):

`Data Source=C:\\...\\SqlServerDbExample.mdf`

SQL Server is a *server* application, you don't connect to a file name*, you connect to the server to it via a network address or name.

Examples: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/

<sub>*unless you are *attaching*, in which case you do not use `data source` to specify the filename.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
string connectionString =
        "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" + ";" +
        "Integrated Security=SSPI" + ";" + //Windows authentication
        "Persist Security Info=False" + ";" +
        "User Instance=True" + ";" +
        "Data Source=CTE-LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS" + ";" +
        "Initial Catalog=SqlServerDbExample" + ";" + //Database name
        "AttachDBFilename=C:\\..\\SqlServerDbExample.mdf" + ""; //Filename

 OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```